# Best way for Windows Phone Data and Memory

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am designing a Windows Phone App.
The app will download some data from internet (JSON Stream). Such streams may be much larger in size as well are multiple in numbers ( around 30-40 ).
I want the app to have very high performance and achieve some kind of Caching mechanism with such streams.
What is the best way to keep such data.  Either in `Multiple Variables` or `Use File Storage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but what I do is:

- Download the data from the web the first time (the JSON stream)
- Have a cache duration for each item, depending on the type
- Store it directly in `IsolatedStorage` , there is no limit on the file size or number of files you can effectively store there, just keep in mind to not go overboard.
- I don't need to query the data for partial data quickly, but rather to use the data entirely so this works out for me much better than using a database.

Here is my setup:

Backend is a WebAPI app returning enumerables of data transfer objects.

The phone app shares the same data transfer objects, and has a Repository class - which exposes the following methods.

I have a `SimpleRepository` abstract class which exposes the following *abstract* methods:

```
Fetch(string query); //fetch the data from the data source
Store(); // Store the data somewhere
```

Based on those, it implements for you `First(string query)` `Fetch()` and `First()`.

Then, I have a `CachingRepository` class that loads data locally if available and from the web if it's not, it assumes JSON.

It has a constructor that looks like:

```
 CachingRepository(string name, CacheDuration duration,string id)
```

The name of the repo is identical to the resource on the backend, so for example a repository called "Cats" has a corrosponding `/api/phone/Cats` RESTful resource on the backend. The `id` is to differentiate it from other repositories of the same resource. `CacheDuration` is an enum of common cache duration I have, but a TimeSpan might also work.

The repository has two generic parameters - `T` which implements a `ViewModel<U>` class (implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and using the DTO as a model - although that might be too simple for your usage) and `U` that implemnets TipRanksDTO.

Fetch looks something like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Fetch(string queryString)
{
    var localResult = await fetchFromLocal(queryString);
    if(localResult != null){
        return localResult;
    }
    return await fetchFromServer();
}
```

`fetchFromLocal` is a private async method that fetches the data from the `IsolatedStorage` of the app after verifying that the file was not modified before the cache duration. If it is unable to fetch locally, it tries to fetch from the web using `HttpClient`. Both use Newtonsoft.JSON to convert the file/web response directly to C# objects (my DTOs from before).

Now, Store is equally simple - all it does is open the `IsolatedStorage` and push a serialized version of the DTOs to the database, it accepts ViewModels.

Each ViewModel has a `Model` property pointing to the DTO. You might want to have an extra step between your DTOs and models if using DTOs and models is not enough for you or if you want to save anything to the server later.

Then, the usage is something like:

```
 OnPageLoaded += (sender,args) => {
     var repo = new CachingRepository("Cats",CachingDuration.Daily);
     var cats = await repo.Fetch();
     pageViewModel.cats.Replace(cats); //update the ObservableCollection on the VM.
     repo.Store(cats);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for answer! The answer has provided me the way to accomplish the task.

Comment: I'min Finland next month, I'll ask The technical guys there and update if they have Ny improvement suggestions. Good luck.